# Objection.js Extends Multiple Plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, objection.js

There are 2 plugins that I want to use, [objection-password](https://github.com/scoutforpets/objection-password) and [objection-paginator](https://github.com/Batterii/objection-paginator) but all plugins requires to extend some base classes,  which is user class. How do I extend 2 classes in objectionjs ?

My Code

```js
const Password = require('objection-password')()

const Paginator = require('objection-paginator')
const { Model } = require('objection')

// Users class also must extends Passoword to use the method
class Users extends Paginator(Model) {
  static get tableName () {
    return 'users'
  }
}

module.exports = Users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use multiple plugins, you'd need to use mixins from objection package

Here's what your code should look like after using multiple plugins.

```js
const Password = require('objection-password')()
const Paginator = require('objection-paginator')
const { mixin, Model } = require('objection')

// Users class also must extends Passoword to use the method
class Users extends mixin(Model, [
    Password,
    Paginator
]) {
  static get tableName () {
    return 'users'
  }
}

module.exports = Users
```

---

[Reference from objection documentation](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/objection/#mixin)